# How to declare a variable in Big Query when creating a Materialized View

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, materialized-views

I am trying to create a materialized view based on a query. This query relies on some declared variables that work fine when I am just running the query, but when I try to embed it on a CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement I get the error "Query error: Invalid reference to script variable BEGIN_DATE_DASHBOARD".

Here is a simplified verison of what I am trying:

```
DECLARE BEGIN_DATE_DASHBOARD DATE DEFAULT "2023-10-01";

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `project.dataset.table_name`
OPTIONS (
  enable_refresh = true,
  refresh_interval_minutes = 6*60,
  max_staleness = INTERVAL "24:0:0" HOUR TO SECOND
) AS (

WITH

tab_example AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM `some_project.some_dataset.some_table`
  WHERE DATE(window_ts) >= BEGIN_DATE_DASHBOARD
)

SELECT *
FROM tab_example
);
```

When I try to move the "DECLARE" statement to the block after the "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW" I get the "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DECLARE" error.

Do you know how can I declare a variable in a CREATE MATERIALIZE VIEW statement?

Comment: You can’t. How would declaring a variable like that make sense in a materialised view? An MV is basically a table being automatically populated with data based on a schedule; your variable only exists in the context of your session so would not be available to the background process refreshing your MV - plus using a variable in an MV doesn’t make sense as having the definition of an MV change doesn’t make sense. Whatever you are trying to achieve, using an MV doesn’t seem like an appropriate solution

Comment: I have a long MV query and some values are repeated many times in the code, so I have figured using declared variables in the beginning would add readability to it. The query would still work with the values being fixed in the query. Does it make sense creating a procedure and calling it in the MV body?

Comment: It’s probably technically possible to create an SP and call it in your SP. Whether it makes sense would depend on the actual code of the MV/SP, data volumes, frequency of the MV refresh, etc

Comment: Hi @ThiagoSC, Could you confirm if the above comments resolved your issue or not ?